# Reading decimal numbers from txt file and using them in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that reads three points (witch form a triangle) from `b.txt` file given like this:
`(-3,-3) (4,-5.5) (-2,1)`
Later I need to calculate triangle area (P= 15.25 for this example).
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 FILE *fp=fopen("b.txt","r");
 int i=0;
 float x[3],y[3];
 char bracket,comma;
 while(fscanf(fp,"%c%f%c%f%c",&bracket,&x[i],&comma,&y[i],&bracket)==5)
    i++;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   printf("%f %f\n",x[i],y[i]);
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

As a result i am getting:
`0.000000 1102137707490764237397621571846144.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000`

Can anyone give me an idea how to read these numbers?
thanks in advance!
PS
I know how to read numbers (as char) with fgetc but later i cant use them for calculating triangle area.

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%c%f%c%f%c",&bracket,&x[i],&comma,&y[i],&bracket)` looks like UB to me... you are passing the same pointer `&bracket` twice.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i use that bracket just for skipping trash in this case brackets

Comment: @xing still not working

Comment: @xing yes and i tried all the combinations...

Comment: @xing oh yeah it worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your line format is fixed, something like could make the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point {
    float x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("b.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    struct point p[3];
    char bracket, comma;

    fscanf(fp, "(%f,%f) (%f,%f) (%f,%f)", &p[0].x, &p[0].y, &p[1].x, &p[1].y,
           &p[2].x, &p[2].y);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%.2f %.2f\n", p[j].x, p[j].y);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

In order to understand the code I'd recommend you take a look to [fscanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) docs